# Should I comment to update the question instead of flagging?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

Many times questions have comments like this one:

> Show us some sample data and expected results, as formatted text, or
> to make it easier to answer as DDL/DML.

Is it OK to post this type of comment or instead should I flag for  "*Need details or clarity*" or something like "*Need more focus*"?

If it is not OK then should I raise flag like "*It's no longer needed*".

Comment: Flagging and commenting can go hand in hand. The comments will be "no longer needed" after the question is updated with the requested details. Since you have more than 3k, you are voting to close, not flagging. And the appropriate close reason for a question that deserves a comment like the one you show would be _"needs debugging details"_. Please do not refrain from voting to close because you commented.

Comment: If the question is answerable but could use some clarification a comment is fine, no need to close vote. If the question isn't answerable then close vote. Optionally leave a comment to make explicit what you expect to be added. These comments can serve as a guide for re-open voters to see if an edit did indeed resolve the issue.  Only flag these kind of comments as NLN if the post has been edited to satisfy what is suggested in the comment.

Comment: There is no need to use imperative. Something like *"Can you add some sample data and expected results...?"* may work better.